# How do I open a folder that contains files within another folder

Tags: python

for example,

Inside of Folder X there are Folders A, B, and C which contain each files.

How can I create a loop that will go inside of each Fodler A, B, and C, and open the file i need in write mode to make some changes?

Comment: have you looked as `os.walk`?

Comment: Do you want to modify *all* of the files in A, B, and C or only some of them? Are there any folders in X that you do *not* want to modify?

Comment: I would only like to modify the files in folders A, B, and C that have a specific name to them

Comment: i am confused by os.walk, unfortunately

Comment: Do the files you want to open all have the same name?

Comment: yes, they all will have the exact same file name , but are located in seperate folders as each on has different text inside of the file.

Answer (score 0):

To modify the content of different file walking through its subdirectories, you can use os.walk and fnmatch - to choose the proper file format that you want to modify!

```
import os, fnmatch
def modify_file(filepath):
    try:
        with open(filepath) as f:
            s = f.read()
        s = your_method(s) # return modified content
        if s: 
            with open(filepath, "w") as f: #write modified content to same file
                print filepath
                f.write(s)
                f.flush()
            f.close()
    except:
        import traceback
        print traceback.format_exc()

def modifyFileInDirectory(directory, filePattern):
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(directory), followlinks=True):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, filePattern):
            modify_file(filename)


modifyFileInDirectory(your_path,file_patter)
```

Answer (score 0):

If all of the files have the same name (say, `result.txt`), the loop is fairly simple:

```
for subdir in ('A', 'B', 'C'):
    path = 'X/{}/result.txt'.format(subdir)
    with open(path, 'w') as fp:
        fp.write("This is the result!\n")
```

Or, perhaps:

```
import os.path

for subdir in ('A', 'B', 'C'):
    path = os.path.join('X', subdir, 'result.txt')
    with open(path, 'w') as fp:
        fp.write("This is the result!\n")
```

### Update:

With the additional requirements listed in the comments, I recommend you use `glob.glob()`, like so:

```
import os.path
import glob

for subdir in glob.glob("X/certain*"):
    path = os.path.join(subdir, "result.txt")
    with open(path, 'w') as fp:
        fp.write("This is the result\n")
```

In the above example, the call to `glob.glob()` will return a list of all of the subdirectories of X that begin with the literal text "certain". So, this loop might create, successively, "X/certainA/result.txt" and "X/certainBigHouse/result.txt", assuming that those subdirectories already exist.

Comment: would you mind elaborating on this code? i dont fully understand what is goign on here, im a newbie. edit: nvm i understand some of it, however, the A, B, C folders may become A, B, C, D, E at any given time, and editting the code would be a hassle

Comment: Do you want to modify files in all of the subdirectories, or only in some of the subdirectories?

Comment: only in those subdirectories that startswith(a certain string)

Comment: Okay, so my modifying of the files would include, copying the most recently created one, pasting it in the same folder, and renaming it to a certain name.  then modyifng the copy with the new name.  the names will stay consistent through every subdirectory